# How do I get the text under the images?

Tags: html, css

[image: wallet]

As you as see above this is what I currently have. I wish to have the text centered beneath each icon.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="wallet-actions-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12">
        <div class="wallet-action-col">
          <a href="~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml"><img src="~/assets/images/icons/send-icon.png" /></a>Send or Request
          <a href="~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml"><img src="~/assets/images/icons/add-money-icon.png" /></a>Send or Request
          <a href="~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml"><img src="~/assets/images/icons/withdraw-icon.png" /></a>Send or Request
          <a href="~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml"><img src="~/assets/images/icons/security-icon.png" /></a>Send or Request
          <a href="~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml"><img src="~/assets/images/icons/exchange-icon.png" /></a>Send or Request
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
 .wallet-action-col {
   height: 100px;
   width: 90%;
   margin:0 auto;
   border-radius: 5px;
   padding: 15px;
   background-color: #f3f8fb;
   color: #262626;
 }

.wallet-actions-section {
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `<br>` to break the text to the next line. Then create a new `div` that surrounds each "box" with a `class="wallet-action-box"` that centers everything.

```
 .wallet-action-box {
   display:inline-table;
   border:1px solid #aaa;
   text-align:center
 }
```

**[Try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikehomme/nrxgqr5q/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try putting texts in a paragraph tag like this

```
<p>Send or Request</p>
```

as well as others